# oracle SQL convert some columns to rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below and i am trying to find the best query to convert only the months to rows.

```
**CODE  YEAR    JAN FEB MAR**
aa      2017    1   2   3
bb      2017    4   5   6
cc      2017    7   8   9
```

So that the result is:

```
**CODE  YEAR    MONTH   value**
aa      2017    JAN     1
aa      2017    FEB     2
aa      2017    MAR     3
bb      2017    JAN     4
bb      2017    FEB     5
bb      2017    MAR     6
cc      2017    JAN     7
cc      2017    FEB     8
cc      2017    MAR     9
```

Could you please help

Comment: What version of Oracle do you have? If it's at least 11.1, then you can use the solution from the linked thread. If it's earlier, there are other methods to unpivot, which you can also find on this site (good Google skills will help). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124891/oracle-unpivot-columns-to-rows  The trick is the CROSS JOIN to a table with as many rows as the number of columns you need to unpivot.

Comment: @mathguy, thanks for the pre-11.1 link!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you. the solution worked like a charm. I didn't want to read the base table twelve times. I didn't think to use unpivoting. Oracle Version 11.2

Comment: @arvins - please remember to post your Oracle version whenever you ask a question. Here dasblinkenlight guessed (correctly in this case) that you use 11.1 or higher. By posting your Oracle version, you help us help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Setup table with data:

```
Select * into #tmpTbl from (
Select 'aa' as Code,2017 as Yr, 1 as Jan,2 as Feb,3 as Mar UNION ALL
Select 'bb' as Code,2017 as Yr, 4 as Jan,5 as Feb,6 as Mar UNION ALL
Select 'cc' as Code,2017 as Yr, 7 as Jan,8 as Feb,9 as Mar) z
```

Transform query to produce flattened results:

```
SELECT Code, Yr, CrossApplied.Fld, CrossApplied.Val as Value
FROM #tmpTbl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (JAN,'JAN'),
                (FEB,'FEB'),
                (MAR,'MAR'))
        CrossApplied (Val,Fld)
```

[image]

The structure of your data might be better reworked to make the data more inline with how you want it represented. This *works* but its a lot of work around to get there from here.

Comment: This approach is very inefficient. Oracle 11.1 introduced the `unpivot` operator, which does the job in one pass over the base table (your solution requires three). In the old days, the same effect (still with a single pass over the data) was achieved with a Cartesian join to a small table with as many rows as there were columns to unpivot. I offered a link in a Comment under the original question. The solution you posted is correct, but definitely not recommended. That's the reason for my downvote.

Comment: Changed query to use the old ways of doing this, before Oracle 11.1.

Comment: No, you didn't. CROSS APPLY was introduced only in Oracle 12.1. I do strongly encourage you to follow the link I provided in my Comment to the original poster - you will see how CROSS JOIN (not CROSS APPLY) was used in 10.2 and earlier. (Don't worry: the link is to someone else's answer, it is not self-promotion.)