# Oracle: how to query some columns as rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-xe

I use Oracle 11 XE and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tst
(val_a                          NUMBER,
val_b                          NUMBER,
val_c                          NUMBER,
val_sum                        NUMBER,
id                             NUMBER,
dt                             DATE)
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO tst 
VALUES(12,15,17,44,1,TO_DATE('2018-03-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO tst 
VALUES(14,16,11,41,1,TO_DATE('2018-03-03 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO tst 
VALUES(6,7,8,21,2,TO_DATE('2018-03-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

I need to specify two dates and get the following result (`NEW_VAL` are values `SUM`, `A`, `B` and `C` for `ID=1 and DT=2018-03-03`, `OLD_VAL` are values for `ID=1 and DT=2018-03-01`):

```
ID  X   NEW_VAL    OLD_VAL                                
--- --- --------- --------
1   SUM        41        44
    A          14        12
    B          16        15
    C          11        17
```

Below is the query I've implemented:

```
select id, x, new_val, old_val from(

select tst_new.id id0, 1, tst_new.id, 'SUM' x, tst_new.val_sum new_val, tst_old.val_sum old_val from tst tst_new, 
(select * from tst where dt=to_date('01.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) tst_old
where tst_new.dt=to_date('03.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and tst_new.id = tst_old.id and tst_new.id = 1

UNION ALL

select tst_new.id, 2, null, 'A',  tst_new.val_a, tst_old.val_a from tst tst_new, 
(select * from tst where dt=to_date('01.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) tst_old
where tst_new.dt=to_date('03.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')  and tst_new.id = tst_old.id and tst_new.id = 1

UNION ALL

select tst_new.id, 3, null, 'B', tst_new.val_b, tst_old.val_b from tst tst_new, 
(select * from tst where dt=to_date('01.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) tst_old
where tst_new.dt=to_date('03.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and tst_new.id = tst_old.id and tst_new.id = 1

UNION ALL

select tst_new.id, 4, null, 'C', tst_new.val_c, tst_old.val_c from tst tst_new, 
(select * from tst where dt=to_date('01.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) tst_old
where tst_new.dt=to_date('03.03.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and tst_new.id = tst_old.id and tst_new.id = 1

order by 1, 2
)
```

It does provide required result but looks terrible. Is there any way to get that result easier?

Also, if there is no data for the particular date, result should contain ID, X and empty cells. My query just returns nothing if there is no data for any of two dates. How to make query return empty cells if there are no values for that date?

UPDATE: I've seen examples with pivot, but in my case not only columns as rows is required, but also querying data from the same table for different dates. Also, it's not clear how to get empty cells if there is no date for the particular date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORACLE unpivot columns to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124891/oracle-unpivot-columns-to-rows)

Comment: This is a pivot problem. Read this: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Thank you. But how to solve issue with two different dates easier?

Comment: @S.T. Step one - unpivot, preserve dates, step two - pivot back grouping by dates

Comment: @Dmitry Any small example, please?

Answer (score 1):

Inner subquery is result of unpivot, outer - pivoting back:

```
select *
  from (select to_char(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy') dt, vals, dt_vals from tst
        unpivot (dt_vals for vals in (val_a, val_b, val_c, val_sum)))
 pivot (sum(dt_vals) for dt in ('01.03.2018', '03.03.2018'))
 order by 1

VALS    '01.03.2018' '03.03.2018'
------- ------------ ------------
VAL_A             18           14 
VAL_B             22           16 
VAL_C             25           11 
VAL_SUM           65           41
```

Next, you need to specify the rule how to filter these values:

> `NEW_VAL` are values `SUM`, `A` `B` and `C` for `ID = 1 and DT = 2018-03-03`, `OLD_VAL` are values for `ID = 1 and DT = 2018-03-01`

I just hardcoded it "as is":

```
select *
  from (select to_char(dt, 'dd.mm.yyyy') dt, vals, dt_vals from tst
        unpivot (dt_vals for vals in (val_a, val_b, val_c, val_sum))
         where id = 1
         )
 pivot (sum(dt_vals) for dt in ('01.03.2018', '03.03.2018'))
 order by 1

VALS    '01.03.2018' '03.03.2018'
------- ------------ ------------
VAL_A             12           14 
VAL_B             15           16 
VAL_C             17           11 
VAL_SUM           44           41
```