# Identifying changes to data over time

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

Using Oracle Database 11.2.

Problem:  Compare data from two sources and show only the differences.

I'm looking for some really slick solution to automate this comparison for hundreds of tables, each with hundreds of columns, that will work within the context of a query in a report developed in Crystal Reports.  And, yes, I have considered that I took a wrong turn somewhere (Not the Crystal Reports part, though.  I'm stuck with that.) and everything in this description after that point is meaningless.

Set aside thoughts about query or report performance.  I intend to force filters to limit the amount of data that could be processed in a single request.  What I'm asking about here is how to make this generic.  In other words, I don't want to list any specific columns in my query code except, maybe, to distinguish between known grouping or lookup columns -- updated_by, updated_date, etc.  I want to have queries that automatically gather those names for me.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I want to compare data, based on filter criteria, from adjacent rows within a grouping in a table.  Here is simplified example input data:

```
with source_data as (
  select 'a' grp
  , 'b' b
  , 'c' c
  , date '2022-12-01' record_date
  , 'joe' updated_by
  from dual
  union all
  select 'a'
  , 'b'
  , 'd'
  , date '2022-12-02'
  , 'sally' updated_by
  from dual
  union all
  select 'a'
  , 'a'
  , 'd'
  , date '2022-12-04'
  , 'joe' updated_by
  from dual
  union all
  select 'z' a
  , 'b' b
  , 'c' c
  , date '2022-12-01'
  , 'joe' updated_by
  from dual
  union all
  select 'z'
  , 'e'
  , 'c'
  , date '2022-12-08'
  , 'joe' updated_by
  from dual
  union all
  select 'z'
  , 'f'
  , 'c'
  , date '2022-12-09'
  , 'sally' updated_by
  from dual
)
```

| GRP | B | C | RECORD_DATE | UPDATED_BY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | joe |
| a | b | d | 2022-12-02 00:00:00 | sally |
| a | a | d | 2022-12-04 00:00:00 | joe |
| z | b | c | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | joe |
| z | e | c | 2022-12-08 00:00:00 | joe |
| z | f | c | 2022-12-09 00:00:00 | sally |

The need is to see what changes were made by people in certain categories.  For this example, let's say Sally is a member of that group and Joe is not.  So, the only changes I care about are on rows 2 and 6.  But I need to compare each to the previous row, so...

```
,
changed as (
  select sd.*
  from source_data sd
  where updated_by = 'sally'
),
changes as (
  select 'current' as status
  , c.*
  from changed c
  union all
  select 'previous'
  , sd.grp
  , sd.b
  , sd.c
  , c.record_date
  , c.updated_by
  from source_data sd
    inner join changed c on c.grp = sd.grp
                        and sd.record_date = (select max(record_date) from source_data where grp = c.grp and record_date < c.record_date)
)
```

Output from this trivial example seems simple enough.  But when I have hundreds of rows by hundreds of columns to compare, it's not so easy to identify the change.

I have many tables to compare that have the same issue.  Many of the tables have hundreds of columns.  Usually, the difference is in only one or a few of the columns.

This will be done in a report.  I don't have access to create functions or stored procedures, so I doubt I can use dynamic SQL in any way.  This likely has constraints similar to developing a view.

I am NOT using PL/SQL.  (Kinda tired of nearly every Oracle question related to my searches on SO having some relationship to PL/SQL, but no way to filter those out.)

I was thinking that in order to compare the data I'll first want to unpivot it to get a column/value pair on a row...

(Building on the answer to this question:  [ORACLE unpivot columns to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124891/oracle-unpivot-columns-to-rows))

```
, unpivot as (
        Select *
        From (
          Select grp
          , status
          , record_date
          , updated_by
          , Case When C.lvl = 1 Then 'B'
              When C.lvl = 2 Then 'C'
            End col
          , Case When C.lvl = 1 Then coalesce(B, '<null>')
              When C.lvl = 2 Then coalesce(C, '<null>')
            End val
          From changes
          cross join (
            select level lvl
            from dual
            connect by level <= 2
          ) c
        )
        where val is not null
        order by 1, 3, 2 desc
)
```

(Yes, for non-trivial data I'll need to cast the data going into `val` to something more generic, like a string.)

But **how do I programmatically determine the number of columns, the column order, and generate the column names** for both the value of `col` and for the reference for the `CASE` statement in `val`?

I suppose I could use something like this as part of the solution:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
, COLUMN_ID
 
FROM ALL_tab_columns
 
WHERE OWNER = 'MY_OWNER_NAME'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'SOURCE_TABLE'
 
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID
```

But I'm not sure how to dovetail that into the solution in a meaningful way without involving dynamic SQL, which I'm pretty sure I can't do.  And it would probably require referencing columns based on ordinal position, which doesn't appear to be possible in SQL.  Of course, if that would work I could use a similar query to figure out how to handle data types for the `val` column.

Then I need to pivot that to show the before and after values in different columns.  Then I can filter that to only what changed.

```
, 
pivot as (
  select grp
  , record_date
  , col
  , updated_by
  , max("'previous'") val_prev
  , max("'current'") val_curr
  from unpivot
  pivot (
     max(val)
     for status
     in (
          'previous',
          'current'
     )
  )
  group by grp
  , record_date
  , col
  , updated_by
)
select grp
, record_date
, col
, updated_by
, val_prev
, val_curr
from pivot
where val_curr <> val_prev
order by grp
, record_date
```

| GRP | RECORD_DATE | COL | UPDATED_BY | VAL_PREV | VAL_CURR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-12-02 00:00:00 | C | sally | c | d |
| z | 2022-12-09 00:00:00 | B | sally | e | f |

Comment: I'm afraid you have taken off the table the only options that will allow you to accomplish this. There is no way, at all, you can achieve this with pure SQL. It will most definitely require dynamic SQL and PL/SQL. Or, I suppose you could use your client program (Crystal Reports? doubt it is powerful enough for this) to do all this logic and build the dynamic SQL in itself. But really, that is what stored procedures are for. I suggest pushing back on whoever is telling you that you can't have stored procedures.

Comment: It's a cloud vendor.  I doubt they'll be customizing the core system to that extent just for me.  But I suppose I can ask.

Comment: Pull all the data into a local database you manage and then do it however you want?

Comment: Please note that in 12c and above you may declare inline PL/SQL functions, and from 19.7 - SQL Macro with tabular result. It will allow an access to the dynamic SQL. Another option to embed dynamic SQL into a query is to use `DBMS_XMLGEN` with XQuery or `JSON_OBJECT(*)` with subsequent PL/SQL processing per row

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with pure SQL alone. But you can achieve what you want in a single statement using SQL macros - provided you're on an up-to-date version of Oracle Database.

This is an example of a dynamic unpivot macro that converts all the *unlisted* columns to rows:

```
create or replace function unpivot_macro (
  tab       dbms_tf.table_t,
  keep_cols dbms_tf.columns_t
) return clob sql_macro is
  sql_stmt     clob;
  unpivot_list clob;
  select_list  clob;
begin

  for col in tab.column.first .. tab.column.last loop
    if tab.column ( col ).description.name 
         not member of keep_cols then
      unpivot_list := unpivot_list || 
        ',' || tab.column ( col ).description.name;
    end if;
    
    select_list := select_list || 
      ', to_char (' || tab.column ( col ).description.name || ') as ' || 
      tab.column ( col ).description.name;
  end loop;
  
  sql_stmt := 
    'select * from ( 
       select ' || trim ( both ',' from select_list ) || ' from tab 
     )
     unpivot (
       val for col 
       in ( ' || trim ( both ',' from unpivot_list ) || ' )
     )';

  return sql_stmt;
  
end unpivot_macro;
/

select * from unpivot_macro ( 
  source_data, columns ( grp, updated_by, record_date )
);

GRP    RECORD_DATE          UPDATED_BY    COL    VAL    
a      01-DEC-2022 00:00    joe           B      b      
a      01-DEC-2022 00:00    joe           C      c      
a      02-DEC-2022 00:00    sally         B      z      
a      02-DEC-2022 00:00    sally         C      d      
a      04-DEC-2022 00:00    joe           B      a      
a      04-DEC-2022 00:00    joe           C      d
...
```

If the reason for avoiding PL/SQL is you don't have permission to create functions, you can place the macro in the `with` clause.

Here's an example running on 21.3:

```
with function unpivot_macro (
  tab       dbms_tf.table_t,
  keep_cols dbms_tf.columns_t
) return clob sql_macro is
  sql_stmt     clob;
  unpivot_list clob;
  select_list  clob;
begin

  for col in tab.column.first .. tab.column.last loop
    if tab.column ( col ).description.name 
         not member of keep_cols then
      unpivot_list := unpivot_list || 
        ',' || tab.column ( col ).description.name;
    end if;
    
    select_list := select_list || 
      ', to_char (' || tab.column ( col ).description.name || ') as ' || 
      tab.column ( col ).description.name;
  end loop;
  
  sql_stmt := 
    'select * from ( 
       select ' || trim ( both ',' from select_list ) || ' from tab 
     )
     unpivot (
       val for col 
       in ( ' || trim ( both ',' from unpivot_list ) || ' )
     )
     where status is not null';

  return sql_stmt;
  
end unpivot_macro;
  source_data as (
  select 'a' grp, 'b' b, 'c' c, date '2022-12-01' record_date, 'joe' updated_by
  from dual union all
  select 'a', 'z', 'd', date '2022-12-02', 'sally' updated_by  
  from dual union all
  select 'a', 'a', 'd', date '2022-12-04', 'joe' updated_by  
  from dual union all
  select 'z' a, 'b' b, 'c' c, date '2022-12-01', 'joe' updated_by
  from dual union all
  select 'z', 'e', 'c', date '2022-12-08', 'joe' updated_by
  from dual union all
  select 'z', 'f', 'c', date '2022-12-09', 'sally' updated_by
  from dual
), changes as (
  select s.grp, b, c,
         'sally' updated_by, 
         case 
           when updated_by = 'sally' then record_date
           else lead ( record_date ) over ( partition by grp order by record_date ) 
         end record_date,
         case 
           when updated_by = 'sally' then 'current' 
           when lead ( updated_by ) over ( partition by grp order by record_date ) = 'sally'
           then 'previous' 
         end status
  from   source_data s
)
  select * from unpivot_macro (
    changes, columns ( grp, record_date, updated_by, status )
  )
  pivot (
    max ( val ) for status 
    in ( 'previous' prev_val, 'current' curr_val )
  )
  where  prev_val <> curr_val;

G UPDAT RECORD_DATE        C P C
- ----- ------------------ - - -
a sally 02-DEC-22          B b z
a sally 02-DEC-22          C c d
z sally 09-DEC-22          B e f
```

Comment: I'd love to try that.  Unfortunately, the database is running on Oracle 11.2.  Good point, though.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Polymorphic Table Functions.  Available since 18c.  Nice.  I'll be learning more about this tech in hopes of someday using a modern system.  And thanks for the tip making the changes/changed CTEs more concise.

Comment: Minor update:  I got excited to try this out when I noticed one of my database servers was upgraded to 18c.  `ORA-00905: missing keyword`  It looks like this will work in 21c (https://dbfiddle.uk/ewS9Z3vw) but not 18c (https://dbfiddle.uk/vyIr7cA_).